# Pandas categorical series showing duplicate category names. How to find the indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

as I run this code:

```
df19['tipo'] = df19['tipo'].astype('category')
df19.tipo.value_counts()
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
CAS        1269
REF         667
QUE         408
CPPP        190
INH          60
COMP         25
EXC          22
REC          14
ACL           4
NUL           3
CAS           3
REP           3
AMICUS        2
AMI           2
RES           1
HON           1
PRE           1
QUE           1
QUE RET       1
ACLA          1
REV           1
Name: tipo, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, for example, there are  1269 "CAS" rows, but also 3 other "CAS" rows down the line (same happens with "QUE"). I'm confindent they all should be included in the same category, but there's probably some issue with the cell containing the las 3 values, because of which pandas interprets them as a different category. I tried stripping whitespace but it didn't work. What else could be causing this problem? How could I get the indexes of those 3 "CAS" rows so as to manually correct them, if needed?
Thanks!

Comment: Whitespace issues.  `df19['tipo'].unique()`

Comment: You can see all of the unique values by doing `df19['tipo'].unique()`. That will confirm whether or not you have whitespace, but it seems likely that is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
df19['tipo'].str.strip().value_counts()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was indeed using `str.strip()` but it seems changes weren't being retained. I now tried `df19.tipo = df19.tipo.str.strip()` Thank you!!